# Malloc only works with valgrind on. How to debug?

Tags: c, debugging, malloc, valgrind, distcc

to put you in some context here, project i test with valgrind is slightly modified version of [distcc](https://github.com/distcc/distcc). The function that fails has not been changed. The exact place in code that is problematic is function dcc_compress_file_lzo1x in compress.c. It goes like this:

```
int dcc_compress_file_lzo1x(int in_fd,
                        size_t in_len,
                        char **out_buf,
                        size_t *out_len)
{
char *in_buf = NULL;
int ret;

if ((in_buf = malloc(in_len)) == NULL) {
    rs_log_error("allocation of %ld byte buffer failed",
                 (long) in_len);
    ret = EXIT_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    goto out;
}
```

The problem here is malloc in if statement. If I run this program normally it fails randomly(I wrapped whole thing in debug prints), by which i mean that program crashes while doing malloc, without producing error print. On the other hand if i start program with valgrind, everything passes and valgrind doesn't produce anything useful.

I'm not looking for easy answer. I would just like to know how to even debug this, because I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I have no idea, but it smells a bit of undefined behavior.

Comment: This is what we call a Heisenbug. There is no easy answer I'm afraid but you might like to try and hone in on the cause of the problem with a divide-and-conquer approach.

Comment: I'd try to compile it with different optimizations. Maybe alter other options. I'd also try a different compiler. You may have run into a compiler bug.

Comment: You mean different optimisatioin flag for compiling agent code?

Comment: Malloc crashes = there's a heap corruption somewhere. Normally valgrind catches such things but in your case it happens to inhibit the bug it's trying to catch. Which sucks, but such is life.Try building with the address sanitizer.

Comment: Another option is to try malloc debugging. Set MALLOC_CHECK_ environment variable to 3.

Comment: @JakubWalecki Yes. If this is because of a compiler bug, chances are it will only manifest itself on one of the flags. But also try a different compiler.

Comment: @klutt: C'mon, how often did you stumble over a compiler bug in your career? I found one, after plus 30 years.

Comment: "*valgrind doesn't produce anything useful*", the most "unuseful" stuff Valgind creates is "nothing". So please, what does it tell you?

Comment: @alk Very rarely. I don't think it is the case here either, but it could be good to rule that out since it is a pretty easy check.

Comment: Can you open one or more of the core dumps in gdb and post the stack trace(s)?

Comment: Also check if `in_len` is negative or veeeery big number.

Comment: If `malloc()` is crashing, it is because (somewhere else in the overall executable program) the heap was corrupted.  Strongly suggest taking your eye off this specific function call, and commence debugging your program.  The mere detail that it (seemed) to work on the original author's system is no guarantee that something else in the program is not performing some undefined behavior